# How can I sort the TableView A-Z ? ( Swift 3 )

Tags: swift, swift3, tableview

[image][image]

***Haven't Edit yet :***

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let arr = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M"]

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!



//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------//

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell


        cell.thisIsMyText.text = arr[indexPath.row]

        return (cell)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you sort the array (in the screenshot) at *design time*? An explicit sorting in code is pretty silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var sortedArray: [String] = []


...

sortedArray = arr.sorted()
```

and

```
cell.thisIsMyText.text = sortedArray[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: the `sortedArray = arr.sorted()` should I put it in the **viewDidLoad()** ?

Comment: @YuOn You should call that everytime when you are updating the `arr` array. If you array is constant, `viewDidLoad` is good place.

Comment: WHAT THE F.. !!! You solved my problem ! i was trying it on 4:00 pm until now 7:01 pm ! Thank Man ! I will **Check** you answer and **Vote** it ! _**Thanks Mate**_ !!!